# Where can I find a formal grammar for the Perl programming language?

Tags: perl, parsing, grammar

I understand that the Perl syntax is ambiguous and that its disambiguation is non-trivial ([sometimes involving execution of code during the compile phase](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/on-parsing-perl-5.html)). Regardless, does Perl have a formal grammar (albeit ambiguous and/or context-sensitive)?

Comment: Even if, it's propably extremely large. Why do you need it? If you want to practice with grammars, there are alternatives that don't cause heart attacks; if you want to build a perl parser/interpreter - have fun, but first ask yourself why no one else ever tried ;)

Comment: Yes, here's the regex for it: `.*` :-)

Comment: @delnan: I agree, it's crazy. :) I am curious because I am studying parsing theory. I wanted to see an example of a real-life ambiguous grammar (instead of the toy grammars in the text books). I also wanted to see a real-life context-sensitive grammar (if Perl ended up being context-sensitive). As with most things about me, curiosity is usually the motivating factor. :)

Comment: +1 paxdiablo for bringing me the first laugh of the morning. thanks :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [perlfaq7](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html)

> **Can I get a BNF/yacc/RE for the Perl language?**
>
> There is no BNF, but you can paw your
>   way through the yacc grammar in
>   perly.y in the source distribution if
>   you're particularly brave. The grammar
>   relies on very smart tokenizing code,
>   so be prepared to venture into toke.c
>   as well.
>
> In the words of Chaim Frenkel: "Perl's
>   grammar can not be reduced to BNF. The
>   work of parsing perl is distributed
>   between yacc, the lexer, smoke and
>   mirrors."

To see the wonderful set of examples of WHY it's pretty much near impossible to parse Perl due to context influences, please look into [Randal Schwartz's post: On Parsing Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=44722)

In addition, please see the discussion in "[Perl 5 Internals (Chapter 5. The Lexer and the Parser)](http://www.faqs.org/docs/perl5int/lexparse.html)" by Simon Cozens.

---

Please note that the [answer is different for Perl6:](http://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/day-24-the-perl-6-standard-grammar/)

- There exists [a grammar for Perl6](https://github.com/perl6/std/blob/master/STD.pm6)
- Rakudo Perl has [its own version of the grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.pm)

Comment: Smoke and mirrors, brilliant!

Comment: I'm confused by that last quote. Not challenging it but sincerely curious. I was under the impression that the input to yacc (and related compiler compilers) was actually BNF or EBNF or some variant. The output of that feeds into the lexer and so on down stream until the output is spewed. Where am I mistaken in my understanding? thanks

Comment: ah, found this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=471598 and it's got a good discussion that answers my question.

Comment: Yup. That's the "smoke and mirrors" part. Perl 5 syntax is truly odd.

Answer (score 11):

Other people have posted this link before on similar questions, but I think it is fun and has a great case example: [Perl Cannot Be Parsed (A Formal Proof)](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663393).

From that link:

> [Consider] the following devilish
>   snippet of code, concocted by Randal
>   Schwartz, and determine the correct
>   parse for it:
>
> whatever  / 25 ; # / ; die "this dies!";
>
> Schwartz's Snippet can parse two different ways: if whatever is nullary
>   (that is, takes no arguments), the
>   first statement is a division in void
>   context, and the rest of the line is a
>   comment. If whatever takes an
>   argument, Schwartz's Snippet parses as
>   a call to the whatever function with
>   the result of a match operator, then a
>   call to the die() function.
>
> This means that, in order to statically parse Perl, it must be
>   possible to determine from a string of
>   Perl 5 code whether it establishes a
>   nullary prototype for the whatever
>   subroutine.

I just post this part to show that it gets really hard really quickly.

Alternatively, many code/text editors can do a decent (though never great) job of syntax highlighting so you may start at those specs to see what they do. In fact you have inspired me, I think I will post a related question asking what editor best highlights Perl.

Comment: That is an excellent example! Haha, you know you have an odd language when the mere act of *parsing* it inspires people! :)

Comment: Doesn't mean you can't parse it; does mean there are ambiguous parses.  This case is fun because it appears that you have to have a symbol table in order to lex; this begs the question of how can you have a symbol table without already having lexed?  Does Perl only parse lines when it has need to execute them (which would allow it to exectue the defintion of "whatever" first and then exectue this line)?  Does the meaning of this line change if I redefine "whatever" during execution, if I can do that?  More Fun.

Comment: @IraBaxter, I know its been a long time, but I thought I would answer. This example is not the "unparseable" one. If you read the link there is an example which is much more complex and apparently impossible to parse.

Comment: @JoelBerger: I went back and re-read the thread.  I didn't see a "much more complicated example"; all that was there were essentially versions of "You can't statically decide if 'whatever' has an argument list or not".   I buy that you can't statically decide that.  That doesn't mean you can't parse this, just that it has multiple interpretations and there are perfectly adequate parsing technologies for handling this.  Nor does it mean you can't build useful static analyzers; they may not produce good information in this kind of case.  I suspect this kind of thing is rare in real programs.

Answer (score 5):

There is no formal grammar in the sense "this is the specification of Perl 5" (The [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/) effort is trying to fix that, though). But there is a formal grammar in the Perl 5 source code. Of course, understanding the code is most likely not a trivial undertaking.

Jeffrey Kegler has written some good articles about the perl grammar as well on his blog. In particular see, [this post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/jeffrey_kegler/2010/06/parsing-with-ruby-slippers.html) and [this one](http://blogs.perl.org/users/jeffrey_kegler/2010/06/parsing-perl-2-down-the-garden-path.html). The rest of the blog has some quite interesting thoughts on parsing in general as well.

Comment: For reference of readers- Jeffrey Kegler is the author of Marpa, which seems to be the most modern and highly regarded parser for Perl (Marpa::R2); as well as the author of the "Perl cannot be parsed" article that Joel Berger's answer cites.