# What text editor does most accurate job of syntax highlighting Perl

Tags: perl, editor, syntax-highlighting

I know I risk asking a speculative question, however, inspired by this [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625408/where-can-i-find-a-formal-grammar-for-the-perl-programming-language) I wonder which editor does the best job of syntax highlighting Perl. Being well aware of the difficulties (impossibilities) of parsing Perl I know there will not be a perfect case. Still I wonder if there is a clear leader in faithful representation.

N.B. I use `gedit` and it works fine, but with known issues.

Comment: P.S. if it is deemed too speculative, I would be fine marking this CW, but I would like to hear some opinions. I have some really fancy Perl I might need to look over (I have been offered taking over Zoidberg from the original maintainer).

Comment: I'm surrounded by greatness, my first four answerers have a total of 126.8k rep. Yikes!

Comment: I'd say syntax highlighting accuracy is *not* the most important feature in an IDE, since most are "good enough" and if your code breaks highlighting it's often because your code is too complex. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139/what-is-your-favorite-ide-for-perl-development for general editor discussion.

Comment: @Philip, I agree entirely, and thanks for the link, however, for the purposes of this question, that's all I'm curious about.

Comment: @Joel - rep isn't always a measure of greatness :) If you doubt that, check my rep (I'm just run of the mill software engineer who loves developing in Perl with zero lines of CPAN code to my name - though lots of my corporate-owned code is likely more than good enough for CPAN) compared to say, Randal Schwartz's (3k rep). Totally co-incidently, Randal witnessed the very first line of Perl code I ever typed in (it was in company-paid StoneHendge consulting Medium Perl class :)

Comment: @DVK, it was more just a little thing I noticed

Comment: For a while I tried to make the question more specific, but no one responded, so I rolled it back and will pick (almost arbitrarily) Komodo Edit since it was something that I was unaware of previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) does a good job and also scans your modules (including those installed via CPAN) and does well at generating autocomplete data for them.

Comment: I have been playing with this a little since you posted this last night. Looks really nice!

Answer (score 3):

I'm a loyal vim user and rarely encounter anything odd with the native syntax.vim, except for these cases (I'll edit in more if/when I find them; others please feel free also):

- `!!expression` is better written `!!!!expression` (everything after two ! is rendered as a <strike>comment</strike> quoted string; four ! brings everything back to normal)
- `m##` or `s###` renders everything after the # as a comment; I usually use {} as a delimiter when avoiding / for leaning toothpick syndrome
- some edge cases for `$hash{key}` where key is not a simple alphanumeric string - although it's safer to enclose such key names in '' anyway so as to not have to look up the exact cases for when a bareword is treated as a key name

Comment: Also, you can use :TOhtml to publish the highlighted text if the forum doesn't do its own highlighting. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but Padre should be good since it's written in Perl. IIRC It uses PPI for parsing

Comment: Currently still uses Scintilla's highlighting by default because PPI is slow.

Comment: I haven't heard of PPI before, so I just have been doing some reading, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @daxim - so you just need to write Java code in Perl (gazillions of itty bitty files) so PPI only needs to actively parse 1 small file at a time :)))

Answer (score 0):

[jEdit](http://jedit.org)...with the tweaks that I have amassed over the years. It's got the most customizable syntax highlighting I've ever seen.

Comment: Can your tweaks be exported? Seems a shame to have to amass them again if someone has already done so?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) in [CPerl mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CPerlMode). I think it does a terrific job, although similar to Ether's answer, it's not perfect. What's more, I usually use [Htmlize](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize) to publish highlighted code to the web. It's kind of annoying to use fancier forums like this one that do their own syntax highlighting, since it's not really any easier and the results aren't as good.